# Resources for developing Python and Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, user-controls, controls

I would like to ask about some sources for developing applications with Python and Google App Engine.

For example, some controls to generate automatically pages with the insert/update/delete of a database table, or any other useful resources are welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Python community tends to look askance at code generation; so, @Hoang, if you think code generation is THE way to go, I suggest you try just about any other language BUT Python.

@Dominic has already suggested some excellent resources, I could point you to more (App Engine Fan, App Engine Utilities, etc, etc) but they're all based on the Pythonic mindset: understand what you need and what you could be doing, wrap as much of it as feasible into reusable components, reuse those components from your own sources.

You want magic, wizards and code generation that basically excused you (in theory) from STUDYING and UNDERSTANDING: give up on Python, it's SO not the language for **that**,

Comment: Agreed. Python is a bit like a racing car. Very powerful, very simple (in theory) but also very hands on. It doesn't baby you, and you need to have a solid understanding of HOW to operate it to get the best from it.

Comment: Hi Alex,
I am not satisfied with your answer. I am not trying to stay away from Python. As I am new to Python and Google App Engine, I just want to ask so people can answer and all of us can benefit. 
In programming language, avoiding "inventing the wheel" is worth to consider.

Comment: @Hoang, I understand: but you're asking if there are "controls" (weird terminology, btw;-) that automatically generate Python code, I explain why there aren't (not ones approved and appreciated by the Python community): there are tools (e.g. App Engine Launcher), there are reusable modules (all over PyPi), there are excellent docs (Dominic mentioned a few, I added some) including training materials, and that's about it. You may not be satisfied with this answer, but, if it reflects the truth, then that must mean you just dislike the truth -- not my issue, if so;-).

Comment: I would answer my question by pointing to a web framework like django and using the django admin interface. I have tried django admin interface, and that is exactly what I want. Thank Alex btw ;) http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/

Answer (score 3):

The google app engine "Getting Started" tutorial is very good. The django documentation is also really detailed. 
Take a look at GoogleIO on youtube and watch some of the tutorials.

Comment: Hi Dominic, what I mean is different, for example, in .net, I can easily find many community controls for solving many problems. Is ther e anything similar to this in Python and Google App Engine?

Answer (score 2):

App Engine Documentation
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/

App Engine Google Group
[http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/)

Google I/O conference videos 
[http://code.google.com/events/io/](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/)

App Engine Cookbook
[http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/)

and, of course, stackoverflow

Comment: Ohh Thank Jonathan, the App Engine Cookbook is the useful one that I haven't known yet!
The App Engine Group seems to make me lost :-s 
The App Engine Documentation is the one I use for reference almost all the time.
Google I/O conference videos are the one that made me change to python proramming just one month ago ;)
I found this page as well, which I think is the summarization of all you have written http://withdjango.com/readers/resources/